# How to upload virtualenv from Windows 7 to CentOS 6?

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, web-deployment

I’m working in a project that requires a certain (server) environment to run, hence it is developed on my local machine(windows 7) and then gets deployed on remote server(centOS 6). I use virtualenv, can I find a way to upload my virtual environment from windows to centOS? Any hint? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to directly upload your virtual environment, as it can contain platform and architecture specific binaries.  What you can do instead is to generate a set of requirements that can be used to recreate the virtual environment.  Quoting the excellent [Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#other-notes):

> In order to keep your environment consistent, it’s a good idea to “freeze” the current state of the environment packages. To do this, run
>
> ```
> $ pip freeze > requirements.txt
> ```
>
> This will create a requirements.txt file, which contains a simple list of all the packages in the current environment, and their respective versions. You can see the list of installed packages without the requirements format using “pip list”. Later it will be easier for a different developer (or you, if you need to re-create the environment) to install the same packages using the same versions:
>
> ```
> $ pip install -r requirements.txt
> ```
>
> This can help ensure consistency across installations, across deployments, and across developers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I still have a concern. If I install other packages on my local machine in the future, I will have to refreeze the requirements and rerun `$ pip install -r requirements.txt` on my server side. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  For packages that are already installed, they should be ignored with a message like: `Requirement already satisfied`.